# Facebook Graph API - Getting An array of User objects who like a page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I am trying to get an array of the people who like a page that I am an admin for. I found a similar approach that works for only objects (i.e Posts, videos, etc ..) using:
    /{object-id}/likes
however it seems like Pages are not counted as objects.

If the data is not available, then how it is available through the facebook website search box: i.e people who like ?

Any help, or even a general guidance is much appreciated.

Comment: no, that´s not possible at all with the api.

Comment: I have been extensively researching the whole day yesterday and yes, it is not possible at all as facebook did close it already, which is total non sense if you ask me my opinion.

Comment: what for would you need the list anyway? you would not be allowed to store the data or use it in any way without user approval, so it totally makes sense. either way, it is how it is, and that question has been asked a lot of times already. that´s why i marked it as duplicate.